# How to create stored procedure phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm try to create store procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserReserveRoom (@user varchar(8))
begin
SELECT FirstName,LastName,Rtype, checkin, checkout, RoomPrice
FROM room INNER JOIN register ON room.username = register.username
WHERE username like @user
end
```

When I executed phpMyAdmin alert like this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@user varchar(8)) begin 
SELECT FirstName,LastName,Rtype, checkin, checkout, Ro' at line 1
```

I try to put:

> delimiter 
>     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UserReserveRoom;

But it doesn't work. How I can do to fix it??
I appreciate any feedback from users who have experience in such matters. 
Thanks you.

Comment: as it's a procedure you'll need to define whether your `user` variable is input or what : try `CREATE PROCEDURE UserReserveRoom(IN user VARCHAR(8))`

Comment: The error message tells you to check for "the right syntax to use near '**@user** varchar(8)..'".  That differs form what you posted in the first block of code.

Comment: @eggyal so sorry I put wrong one. thank you I will edit it

Comment: What on Earth prompted to you to stick in `@` characters that weren't there before?

Comment: ... and since the edit - you don't stick `@` on input variables in stored procedures/functions - that's just for declaring variables with `SET` in queries you're directly executing.

Comment: quite likely you hit a "username is ambiguous" error as well

Comment: @eggyal When I learning at school and using SQLServer, teacher teach me to do like that but it doesn't work on phpMyAdmin so I don't know how to fix it. :'(

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are two competing products, from different developers.  There are a number of differences between them, of which this is one.

Answer (score 0):

you call it like so also

```
CALL UserReserveRoom('whatevervalue s_user is here');
```

or with php:

```
$mysqli->query("CALL UserReserveRoom('whatevervalue s_user is here')");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's work. I my class room, my teacher tell me to use 'EXEC' is it like 'CALL' ??

Comment: Yeah the native Mysql to execute a stored proc is Call.. if your dealing with in and out parameters your call them like this and then to display them you have to select them CALL UserReserveRoom('whatevervalue s_user is here');  your tutor probably meant that in php pdo you use $mysqli->exec("CALL UserReserveRoom('whatevervalue s_user is here')") Im going to do a basic tutorial on my site on stored procs and php next weekend, you should check it out lassieslab.paddyosullivan.ie

Comment: you previously asked what was 'IN' so basically in is the parameter you feed the stored proc. for instance if i have a dating site and i want to display the users profile i would feed the ID as the IN parameter and the OUT parameters would be the info relating to the row that matches the ID i want to display from that such as users sex, address etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax in newer versions of phpMyAdmin

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UserReserveRoom; 

CREATE PROCEDURE UserReserveRoom (IN user varchar(8))

SELECT FirstName,LastName,Rtype, checkin, checkout, RoomPrice
FROM room INNER JOIN register ON room.username = register.username
WHERE username like user;
```

And then, you call the procedure via phpMyAdmin using the following syntax:

```sql
SET @user='xyz';
CALL UserReserveRoom(@user);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UserReserveRoom(IN s_user VARCHAR(8))
BEGIN
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Rtype, checkin, checkout, RoomPrice
    FROM room INNER JOIN register ON room.username = register.username
    WHERE room.username = s_user;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: It's work! Thank you so much. But I confused a little bit, what does 'IN' mean?? Is it tell about variable that come in??

Comment: Yeah - with a Stored Procedure you need to declare whether a variable is an input parameter (**IN**), an output parameter (returned by the Procedure, **OUT**) or both (**INOUT** a variable modified and returned by the procedure) - if you're modifying/returning data (in PHP/PDO) you'd bind the parameter to the statement with `->bindParameter()` ... which is why it has to be passed by reference, the variable goes into the stored procedure, is modified, and comes back out again.

Comment: This piece of code doesnt works in the newer versions

Comment: @SHAKIRSHABBIR - to be fair I answered this almost a year ago; it was correct at the time *shrugs*

Comment: @CD001 - The comments are not to disgrace anyone, but to help everyone. You might be right in saying that the code worked previously, but devs look for quick solutions and in recent times, all have newer versions.